# JSON data is not coming in response Headers in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, json

I am using `CocoaHTTPServer` for my server connection. In my html page (web client) have some JSON data, but when I am getting response I am not getting the JSON data in header file.

Below is my code :

**HTML Page :**

```
    endAPSession: function (success, fail) {
    this.endApSessionIssued = true;
    console.log('endAPSession.');
    this.proxyAjax({
      url: 'http://192.168.123.1/stw-cgi-rest/network/wifi/connect',
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password,
      method: 'PUT',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: 'application/json'
    })
    .done( function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
      device.endApSessionIssued = false;
      console.log("endAPSession success:", arguments);
      return success(jqXHR);
    })
    .fail( function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
      device.endApSessionIssued = false;
      console.log("endAPSession fail:", jqXHR);
      return fail(jqXHR);
    })
  },

    var data = {
      SSID: network.name,
      Password: password,
      SecurityMode: network.security
    };
```

I am adding this Headers :

```
 -(void) addHeaders:(HTTPMessage *)response {
    [response setHeaderField:@"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value:@"*"];
    [response setHeaderField:@"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value:@"accept,x-forwarded-url, authorization, content-type,username,password, camera-data"];
    [response setHeaderField:@"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value:@"HEAD,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,POST"];
    [response setHeaderField:@"Access-Control-Max-Age" value:@"86400"];
    [response setHeaderField:@"Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value:@"content-type, content-length, connection, date, server, x-www-authenticate"];
}
```

I am getting below Response :

```
     Accept = "*/*";
    "Accept-Encoding" = "gzip, deflate";
    "Accept-Language" = "en-us";
    Authorization = "Digest username=\"admin\",realm=\"iPolis\",nonce=\"2f65566a6c6239a1358732f8bfe08909\",uri=\"/stw-cgi-rest/network/wifi/connect\",qop=auth,nc=00000001,cnonce=\"7007d989\",response=\"dae876901c002f20b3baa100580a1634\"";
     Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 63;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
     Host = "127.0.0.1:8090";
     Origin = "http://localhost:8090";
     Referer = "http://localhost:8090/";
     "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13F69";
password = "";
     username = admin;
    "x-forwarded-url" = "http://192.168.123.1/stw-cgi-rest/network/wifi/connect";
```

Here I am not getting the JSON response. Here `Content-Length` is coming 63. It means data is there. But its not coming.

JSON should be like this :

```
  "camera-data" = "{\"SSID\":\"HomeNetwork\",\"Password\":\"1234567\",\"SecurityMode\":\"PSK\"}";
```

If I am adding below code in my html page the above JSON is coming in my response, but I don't want to change my HTML page.

```
 if(proxyOpts.data != null) {
        proxyOpts.headers['camera-data'] = proxyOpts.data;
  }
```

So please guide me how can I get JSON in response header ? How can I get `camera-data` in my response.

Comment: You've shown code for adding the headers to the response, but you say the problem is that the response _body_ is missing.  Where is the Objective-C code you're using to write the JSON data into the response?  Also, your `done` handler isn't doing anything with the returned `data`.

Comment: write the JSON data into the response is handle by CocoaHTTPServer class.

Comment: I just want to know how the data will come outside of header or inside header. Have to add any header ya what I have to do ?

Comment: If `CocoaHTTPServer` is what's sending the data, then it's up to that class.  If you have the source-code for it, it should be simple to determine.  Although I consider it to be _extremely_ unlikely that the JSON response data would be placed in a header.  That just wouldn't be proper use of the protocol.  The response data goes in the body, not the header section.

Comment: My question is how to get   data: JSON.stringify(data) , this data in my http server class from html page ?

Comment: JSON response data would not be placed in a header, it should be come outside of header. But I am not getting that one only ?

Comment: Your `done` handler is declared like `function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR )`, the JSON that the server sends back should be passed in as the `data` parameter.  However note that `"camera-data" = "{\"SSID\":\"HomeNetwork\",\"Password\":\"1234567\",\"SecurityMode\":\"PSK\"}"` is *not valid JSON*, and won't be parsed by jQuery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116950/discussion-between-s-r-nayak-and-aroth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize, to be sure I'm getting this correctly, you have a web client containing some HTML & JavaScript code. Using this JavaScript code, you're sending a request to a web server you're hosting with `CocoaHTTPServer`. Within this request, you're sending JSON data with `data: JSON.stringify(data)`. You want to get and use this data on the server side. Is that correct ?

If that's correct, on the server side, you'll have a custom subclass of `HTTPConnection` for all incoming connections within `CocoaHTTPServer`:

```
[httpServer setConnectionClass:[YourConnectionClass class]];
```

Then, you'll have in this subclass your custom implementation of `(NSObject<HTTPResponse> *)httpResponseForMethod:(NSString *)method URI:(NSString *)path`. This method will be called to get a response for every requests. In this method, you'll be able to check for example if the method of the request is `PUT` like you specified in your JavaScript code, to get the body of your request which contains your data, etc.

```
- (NSObject<HTTPResponse> *)httpResponseForMethod:(NSString *)method URI:(NSString *)path {
    // Check if the method is PUT.
    if ([method isEqual:@"PUT"]) {
        // Get the data sent in this request.
        NSData *requestData = [request body];

        // Transform the data into usable JSON.
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:requestData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        // At this point, you have your json data send in the request, you can do anything with it.
        // ...
        // ...
    } 

    // ...
    // Return a proper response depending on the request.
    // ...
}
```

You also need to be sure to allow the different methods you'll be using, `PUT` obviously and `OPTIONS` to avoid CORS issues.

```
- (BOOL)supportsMethod:(NSString *)method atPath:(NSString *)path
{
  if ([method isEqualToString:@"PUT"])
    return YES;

  if ([method isEqualToString:@"OPTIONS"])
    return YES;

  return [super supportsMethod:method atPath:path];
}
```

Since the PUT method send data, we also need to handle this data on the server-side too using the `processBodyData` method which by default is empty and needs to be overridden.

```
- (void)processBodyData:(NSData *)postDataChunk
{
    [request appendData:postDataChunk];
}
```

With these 3 methods in my `HTTPConnection` subclass, I can use a similar JavaScript code to the one in the question:

```
var data = { name: "HiDeo", location: "Internet", other: "test" };

$( document ).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
   method: "PUT",
   url: "http://localhost:12345/",
   data: data,
   username: "testUsername",
   password: "testPassword",
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   contentType: 'application/json'
 })
 .done(function( msg ) {
   console.log(msg)
 });
```

});

If I `NSLog(jsonData);` on the server-side, I'll get the following output:

```
{
    location = Internet;
    name = HiDeo;
    other = test;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur reply. exactly ur understanding is correct. But I am getting [request body] is null. So NSDictionary also coming null.

Comment: I edited my answer to add more details over the different steps I took to get a working example close to yours.

Comment: I have all method. Only this method was not there. I add according to u. - (void)processBodyData:(NSData *)postDataChunk

Comment: I don't want to change my html page. Its download from Cloud. So i can't change anything.

Comment: You can still use your JavaScript code in your HTML page, I made one similar to you using jQuery since you mentioned using it. It does pretty much the same thing, right? Regarding your missing method, it's should bring us one step closer to the problem, it's mandatory to get the data in POST/PUT request.

Comment: yes but I am not getting anything in body. I am getting body like this <>

Comment: The only way for me to get `<>` for the `[request body]` is not appending the data, did you add the `processBodyData` method like in my example ?